# Checking for AWS service availability in a aws Region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, sdk

Have aws java sdk/Api is available for getting AWS service availability with service name in a aws Region.

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html -> `get_available_regions`

Comment: i need java code

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are wanting to discover whether a particular AWS service is available in a particular region.

For this, you can query **AWS Systems Manager Parameter store**.

From [New – Query for AWS Regions, Endpoints, and More Using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-query-for-aws-regions-endpoints-and-more-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/):

> Here’s how to get the list of regions where a service (Amazon Athena, in this case) is available:

```
$ aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
  --path /aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/athena/regions --output json | \
  jq '.Parameters[].Value'
"ap-northeast-2"
"ap-south-1"
"ap-southeast-2"
"ca-central-1"
"eu-central-1"
"eu-west-1"
"eu-west-2"
"us-east-1"
"us-east-2"
"us-gov-west-1"
"ap-northeast-1"
"ap-southeast-1"
"us-west-2"
```

The AWS SDK for Java can call Systems Manager in the same way.